# Change font-size of domain axis label and range axis label for jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart, font-size, axis-labels

My goal is to increase the size of **"Revenue ($) " and "Years"**. But I do not know how. I am able to increase the "Apples, Durians,Oranges" and "2012, 2013".

Below are my codes.

[image]

```
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart3D("", // chart title
                "Years", // domain axis label
                "Revenue ($)", // range axis label
                dataset, // data
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // orientation
                false, // include legend
                false, // tooltips
                false);

CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
        CategoryAxis axis = plot.getDomainAxis();

        CategoryPlot p = chart.getCategoryPlot(); 
         ValueAxis axis2 = p.getRangeAxis();

        Font font = new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 25);
        axis.setTickLabelFont(font);
        Font font2 = new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 15);
        axis2.setTickLabelFont(font2);

        LegendTitle legend = new LegendTitle(plot.getRenderer());

        Font font3 = new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 20); 
        legend.setItemFont(font3); 
        legend.setPosition(RectangleEdge.BOTTOM); 
        chart.addLegend(legend);
```

Comment: The fastest way to find the answer to this would be to read the API docs (http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/CategoryAxis.html) and scan all the setXXX() methods (including the inherited methods).  setLabelFont() should jump out at you as something worth trying.

Comment: See also [*Help with font size please*](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=120504).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use

```java
CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
Font font3 = new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 25); 
plot.getDomainAxis().setLabelFont(font3);
plot.getRangeAxis().setLabelFont(font3);
```